# Probability of consecutive mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability

For my research, I need to formulate the following probability:
There are four possible events. Probability of two of them is $P_1$, probability of other two is $P_2$. So $2P_1+2P_2 = 1$. They may happen without replacement.

First I need to find a probability of two of those events happening after each other. I figured that this probability should be the following:

$$P_{12} = P_1\frac{P_2}{1-P_1}$$ for different events and

$$P_{11} = P_1\frac{P_1}{1-P_1}$$ for the same ones.

Now I need to formulate the same but for three events in a row. Using the same reasoning, I do

$$P_{121} = P_{12}\frac{P_1}{1-P_1-P_2} $$

but it doesn't look correct when I plot it. 
Could anyone clarify this for me? 
Thanks.

Comment: probably better off writing it as a markov chain.

Comment: Sorry I have figured it out myself - the answer that I have written is actually right, wrong was the way I was validating it.

Comment: 2Lost1: by the way, if I understand Markov chains correctly, they will not work here because the probability of the 3rd event depends on the outcome of the 1st event, and not only on the 2nd.

Comment: 2nd order markovk chain